# How to remove the currency in the dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

*here are the data frame look like*

```
CCD     CFO     CP3     DHC     ERS     FRO     HDI     IHI     IPI     ODF     PAE  
                       0 EGP           40 USD          210 USD  
inclu                         1500 THB                 70 INR          855 EUR
       inclu                                   60 CNY
```

**The first line is the column name, what I want to do is to remove the currency and keep the number and 'inclu'.
Calculate the total number of each row.**

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) for remove space(s) or uppercase strings to end of value in all columns:

```
df = df.replace(r'(\s+[A-Z]+)$', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer what if  I want to calculate the sum of each row? how to do that?

Comment: @huoshankou - You can try `df['SUM'] = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').sum(axis=1)` ?